# Can getActivity() be null, if called inside a button listener of an AlertDialog which is instantiated inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

I need to finish some Activity if "OK" button of an AlertDialog is clicked. The Activity is just a container for another Fragment; And AlertDialog is built inside the Fragment. Something like this:

```
public class F extends Fragment {

...

    public void confirmExit() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            ...
            .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> getActivity().finish())
            ...
            .show();
    }

...

}
```

Now, the AndroidStudio shows me this warning:

> Method invocation 'finish' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

So it thinks that getActivity() may return null. But is this even possible? If the Dialog is on the screen and is interactable, can the underlying Activity be null? If not how to suppress this warning without adding boilerplate code?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
It may crash because you call `getActivity()` on an interface and not on the Fragment.

You need to store an instance of your Activity outside the DialogInterface and you will be able to pass the instance on the DialogInterface.

Should be something like that.

```
public class F extends Fragment {
    private Context mContext;
...
    @Override
    void onAttach(Context context) {
        mContext = context
    }

    public void confirmExit() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            ...
            .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> ((YourParentActivity) mContext).finish())
            ...
            .show();
    }

...

}
```

Comment: In the code in the question above, the listener ends up being an anonymous inner class that has a reference to its outer class.  So, what object do you think owns the getActivity() method?

Comment: No it will not crash! Actually it is working right now.
The question is about a possible circumstance which may crash the app not will or will not crash.